# Oozie workflow xml error

Tags: hadoop, oozie

Running an oozie workflow that include these lines:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="cs-wf-fork-join">
    <start to="fork-node"/>

    <fork name="fork-node">
        <path start="my-node" />
    </fork>
```

I get the following error:

> Error: E0701 : E0701: XML schema error, cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element
>   'fork' cannot have character [children], because the type's content
>   type is element-only.

I'm using this guide: http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2013/10/executing-oozie-workflow-with-pig-hive.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the [schema](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.1/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#Appendix_A_Oozie_XML-Schema), seem that you need at least 2 element in the fork:

```
<xs:complexType name="FORK">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="path" type="workflow:FORK_TRANSITION" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="workflow:IDENTIFIER" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Also, you can use [command line validation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Validating_a_Workflow_XML) for validate the xml